# What makes sure a thread sees the latest value when passing data between two threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, pinvoke

I'm using native library via PInvoke calls which returns Byte* and want to make sure that in a producer/consumer scenario that the consumer thread gets the latest data.

I have a very contrived example here, to try to illustrate what I'm asking. I'm aware of the 'hot loop' in the `Consumer` (it's just an example, the real code is much larger and would not be feasible to paste here).

```
public unsafe class ThreadExample {
  class PInvokeResult {
    public Byte* Data;
    public Int32 Length;
  }

  // Shared Objects Used For Synchronization
  Object SyncRoot = new Object();
  Queue<PInvokeResult> WorkQueue = new Queue<PInvokeResult>();

  // Producer Thread
  void Producer() {
    while (true) {
      PInvokeResult workItem;
      workItem = new PInvokeResult();
      workItem.Data = PInvokeNativeLongRunningCall(out workItem.Length);

      lock (SyncRoot) {
        WorkQueue.Enqueue(workItem);
      }
    }
  }

  // Consume Thread
  void Consumer() {
    while (true) {
      bool workAvailable = false;
      PInvokeResult workItem = null;

      lock (SyncRoot) {
        if (WorkQueue.Count > 0) {
          workItem = WorkQueue.Dequeue();
          workAvailable = true;
        }
      }

      if (workAvailable) {
        ProcessWorkItem(workItem);
        PInvokeReturnPointerBuffer(workItem.Data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is the lock here enough to make sure that the data that is read from the `Byte*` pointer on PInvokeResult never points to 'stale' data for the consumer?

What I mean by stale data here is this case:

1. One specific Byte* buffer gets returned from the `PInvokeNativeLongRunningCall` invocation.
2. The buffer is passed from the producer to the consumer, this uses locking on the SyncRoot to make sure access to the Queue is safe.
3. The consumer does some work on the item and then returns it to the native code via `PInvokeReturnPointerBuffer`
4. The buffer is then recycled and re-used on the native side and the data in the buffer is first set to all zeroes and then written to again.
5. The cycle then starts over from `1.`

When the buffer for the second times comes to the Consumer, how can I be sure that the data that it sees it the latest new data that was written to by the PInvoke call?

This question is purely from the C# perspective, I know that the native code is fine and solid, it's a well used library.

Is this even something that a language has to account for, or is this completely handled by the CPU itself?

Comment: Yes, the lock is enough.  You get the memory barrier it uses for free.

Comment: Even if the data i'm scared of getting 'stale' is from some native part of the running application? I assume it doesn't really matter, the CPU doesn't care about what type of language is executing, etc.

Comment: Right, the processor knows only one kind of data.